# Using JavaScript, can I save images as their CSS thumbnailed sizes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Perhaps an odd use case, but assume the following code, where image1.jpg is 1920x1080:

```
<a href="http://example.com/dir/photos/image1.jpg" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://example.com/dir/photos/image1.jpg">
</a>
```

As you can see, the image loads in full on the page; however, not shown above is CSS that's being used to display that image as a thumbnail on the page (say, 480 x 270).

Yes, this is a horribly unoptimized practice.

The issue I'm having is that a client has hundreds of these occurrences happening across multiple pages. I'm trying to quickly create thumbnail versions of the images exactly as they're sized on the page. Some images are wider/taller than others, and image/folder names are all over the place, so creating thumbnails of each image from the rendered page is what I need for what I would like to accomplish.

Ideally, I'm thinking of using JS (or jQuery, if anyone knows of any particular methods) to target all the images (however that needs to happen) to ultimately create and download/save thumbnails as their CSS-sized on-page representations.

I hope this question makes sense. I would be happy to clarify more if need be. Thank you for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: Sounds like something that should be handled on the backend, not the frontend

Comment: That is unfortunately not a solution I have available to me right now. I need to create the thumbnailed versions from the rendered page, store them somewhere myself, then re-link each img tag accordingly. I'm just trying to reduce an already lengthy workload given the circumstances I'm bound by.

Comment: If your backend is running with php, you may try an extension `slir`: https://github.com/lencioni/SLIR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code, takes all images from a page, and scales them to the effective CSS size being used for rendering, then performs the download.
The way it works is the following:

1. Generates an empty canvas element
2. Generates an image, and loads the original image element source in it
3. Dumps the content of the new image in the canvas, using the original image sizes.
4. Dumps the content of the canvas back into the original image element
5. Executes the download() function (only works in chrome)

```js
function scaleToElementSize(img){
  return new Promise( (resolve,reject)=>{
    // create an empty canvas and assign to it
    // the rendered proportions of the provided image 
    let c = document.createElement('canvas');
    c.height = img.height;
    c.width = img.width ;
    const ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    // create an image element, and load the source
    // image in it
    let i = new Image();
    i.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
    i.src = img.src;

    // when image is loaded, copy its contenta scaled     
    // into the canvas, dump the resulting scaled
    // image back, to the original image, and download
    i.onload = ()=>{
       ctx.drawImage(i, 0, 0, c.width, c.height); 
       img.setAttribute('filename', img.src);
       img.onload = null;
       img.src =  c.toDataURL("image/png");
       resolve();
    }
  });
}

function download(img){
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = img.getAttribute('filename');
  link.href = img.src.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");;
  link.click();
}

 document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach( img=>{
   img.onload= function(){ 
     scaleToElementSize(img)
     .then( ()=> download(img) )
   }
 })
```

```html
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/286?a.jpg" width="100">
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/139?b.jpg" width="200">
<img src="https://placekitten.com/408/287?c.jpg" width="110">
```

Comment: Does this solve the requirement of saving the images?

Comment: I updated my answer, now it automatically downloads the re-scaled images (only chrome)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! What a cool solution. I had to make one small adjustment for my particular use case within TamperMonkey, which was to nix the "img.onload=", instead wrapping that function inside an IIFE. Then, I wrapped the full querySelectorAll() block in a named function, which I in turn call via a setTimeout() that waits long enough to ensure the page has fully loaded all images. The "img.onload=" wasn't playing nicely with any of the @run-at params in TamperMonkey (not your fault). Thank you again for sharing your solution; I'll definitely be studying it more in-depth!